# Immigration authority, foreign authority, alien authority: do these point to the same thing in Berlin, Germany?

Tags: germany, working-visas, foreign-employment

Back on Monday, I had my work visa interview with section 81a advance approval document in the German Embassy. My company is in Berlin, so my employer had got the 81a issue document issued by **Landesamt Für Einwanderung**.

During the interview, the interviewer had a sample document, and he clearly told me that the document must be issued by the alien authority, and I kept telling him that every state in Germany has a different alien authority, for example, in Frankfurt it's known as **Ausländerbehörde Frankfurt**

Although I have done my own research, I'd just like to confirm that words like foreign authority, alien authority, immigration authority for Berlin always point to **Landesamt Für Einwanderung**, or these are different things?

P.S: in the coming days, I will have my interview again in the diplomatic mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Since 2020-01-01, the former **Berliner Ausländerbehörde** is called **Landesamt für Einwanderung**. It often takes time for such name changes to be used consistently and often even longer before many becomes aware or used to the name change.

Since most towns (or county (**Kreis**)) in Germany have one for their areas of responsiblity, the name will often include the city, county name.

Since the organization is done per state, each state may have a different name for the authority:

- Ausländerbehörde
- Ausländeramt
- Zentrale Ausländerbehörde
- Fremdenamt/polizei/wesen (Austria)
- Migration (Switzerland)

---

**Sources**:

- [Ausländerbehörde – Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ausl%C3%A4nderbeh%C3%B6rde)
- [Namenswechsel: Berliner Ausländerbehörde ist jetzt Einwanderungsamt | rbb24](https://www.rbb24.de/politik/beitrag/2020/01/umbenennung-auslaenderbehoerde-landesamt-einwanderung-berlin.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was humiliated during my interview; I kept telling them that Landesamt für Einwanderung is actually the foreign authority in Berlin, but they kept telling me that the name would always start with Ausländer.

Comment: @ArslanAli Well, thats because until 2019 they did. I only noticed it in April.

Comment: To add to this excellent answer: in Berlin, most people still call it "Ausländerbehörde" in 2021, or sometimes use the "LAE" abbreviation.